# Как обращаться к стилю элемента из чистого js

Tags: javascript, css3

здравствуйте
как получить стиль элемента dom в js?
например

```
elem = document.getElementById('id');
```

как вытащить у этого элемента стили css?

Comment: Коллега, посмотрите ваши отклонённые правки и почитайте про [внутристрочное форматирование](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/), некоторые ваши правки избыточны.

Answer (score 2):

вот так попробуйте

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
var out = "";
var elementStyle = element.style;
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);

for (prop in elementStyle) {
  if (elementStyle.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    out += "  " + prop + " = '" + elementStyle[prop] + "' > '" + computedStyle[prop] + "'\n";
  }
}
console.log(out)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <body style="font-weight:bold;">

    <div style="color:red" id="myElement">..</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: объясни первую строку вывода: `0 = 'color' > 'animation-delay'`

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `elem.style`, очевидно же.

https://puzzleweb.ru/javascript/element_style.php

Comment: так можно получить только стили установленные через атрибут `style`